# CharConverter unknown errors

Tags: c++, modularization

I'm creating a program here are the specifications:

> Create a CharConverter class that performs various operations on strings. It should have the following two public member functions to start with.
>
> The uppercase member function accepts a string and returns a copy of it with all lowercase letters converted to uppercase. If a character is already uppercases or is not a letter, it should be left alone.
>
> The properWords member function accepts a string of words separated by spaces and returns a copy of it with the first letter of each word converted to uppercase.
>
> Write a simple program that uses the class. It should prompt the user to input a string. Then it should call the properWords function and display this resulting string. Finally, it should call the uppercase function and display this resulting string.

I wrote the program without modularizing it to make sure I converted everything right. Now that I'm trying to modularize I'm getting errors I don't know what they mean, when compiled:

[image: errors]

here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<ctype.h>

using namespace std;

class CharConverter {

public:
void uppercase(string, int);
void properWords(string, int);

};

void CharConverter::uppercase(string myString, int s) {

s = myString.length();

for (int i = 0; i <= s; i++) {

    myString[i] = toupper(myString[i]);

}

cout << myString << endl;

}

void CharConverter::properWords(string myString, int s) {

for (int i = 0; i <= s; i++) {
    myString[i];

    myString[0] = toupper(myString[0]);

    if (myString[i] == ' ') {
        myString[i + 1] = toupper(myString[i + 1]);
    }
}

cout << myString << endl;
}


int main() {

void properWords(string, int);
void uppercase(string, int);


string sentence;
int size;

cout << "Enter a sentence you want converted to all uppercase letters and 
set up with proper uppercase letters." << endl;
getline(cin, sentence);

size = sentence.length();

properWords(sentence, size);

uppercase(sentence, size);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the error messages as text.

Comment: if you click on image it will enlarge.

Comment: @KennyFreeman that is not the point. StackOverflow guidelines are to post code and error messages as text, not images. Links to external resources break over time. Everything should be self-contained in the question itself as much as possible. Images should be used to enhance the question, not host the content of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beginning of main

```
int main() {

void properWords(string, int);
void uppercase(string, int);
```

you declare two *other* functions, not part of `CharConverter`. And then you call those functions, not the ones you defined earlier.

And so the compiler (linker actually) complains that it cannot find these non-member functions. And that is true, they don't exist.

Now you have to decide if you need a class. In that case create a class object and call the member functions. Or skip the class declaration and make the functions free functions.

Comment: I figured it was something simple. C++ seems a lot more complicated than I remember doing this in Java was. Thanks.

Comment: @Kenny - C++ is nothing like Java. You can have a class with all `static` functions in C++ too, but you don't have to. You can have just functions and no class. Some of us believe that *this* is less complicated. :-)